# EJB3Unit "no metadata was found for" InterceptorClass

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, ejb

Hia all,

I've got a service which uses EJB and EJB3Unit for testing.  I've created an interceptor and decorated a method with it.

Now, when I run the unit tests I get the following errors:

Tests in error:

```
testProcessLibraryAdditionEvent(LibraryAdditionBusinessDelegateImplTest): Internal problem as no metadata was found for 'LogMetricInterceptor'.
```

I'm having a bit of a nightmare finding out what I should be doing:

- What is this "Metadata" that I'm missing?
- How do I populate it to make EJB3Unit happy?

To summerise... *What's going on?*

Thanks in advance.

Dave